# Optimizan ORDER BY & LIMIT queries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I trying to optimize query like this:

```
SELECT sql_no_cache t.topic_id 
FROM   blog AS b, 
       topic AS t 
WHERE  t.topic_publish = 1 
       AND t.topic_type <> 'topic' 
       AND t.topic_lang = 'en' 
       AND t.blog_id = b.blog_id 
ORDER  BY t.topic_date_add DESC 
LIMIT  50;
```

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `topic` (
  `topic_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `blog_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `topic_type` enum('topic_catalog','topic','link','question','photoset') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'topic',
  `topic_lang` varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'russian',
  `topic_title` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `topic_date_add` datetime NOT NULL,
  `topic_date_edit` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `topic_publish` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`topic_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `topic_date_add`     (`topic_type`,`topic_lang`,`topic_publish`,`blog_id`,`topic_id`,`topic_date_add`),
  KEY `blog_id` (`blog_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `topic_date_add` (`topic_date_add`,`topic_type`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Table `topic` contains about 1M records and works very good (about 0.0016s) without `ORDER  BY`.

With `ORDER  BY t.topic_date_add DESC` query is executing much longer (about 2.8083 on the same machine)

`Explain` on query with `order` looks like:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------+----------------+---------+--------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys        | key            | key_len | ref                | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------+----------------+---------+--------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | index  | blog_id,topic_rating | topic_date_add | 9       | NULL               |   50 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,blog_type    | PRIMARY        | 4       | sku_prod.t.blog_id |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------+----------------+---------+--------------------+------+-------------+
```

I am a newbie in query optimization and can't understand why query with ordering executing so long. From `Explain` looks like performed only 50 rows.

So would be happy to hear any ideas about optimization of this query. if needed I can add any missing information.

Comment: always show schema ... the output from: `show create table xyz` for each table xyz.

Answer (score 1):

First, learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT sql_no_cache t.topic_id 
FROM blog b JOIN
     topic t
     ON t.blog_id = b.blog_id
WHERE t.topic_publish = 1 
      t.topic_type <> 'topic' 
      t.topic_lang = 'en'  
ORDER BY t.topic_date_add DESC 
LIMIT 50;
```

For this query, the optimal index would be `topic(topic_lang, topic_publish, topic_type, blog_id, topic_date_add, topic_id)`.  The last two keys won't be used for ordering but their inclusion makes the index a covering index.

Assuming that `blog_id` always matches something in `blog`, then why not just use:

```
SELECT sql_no_cache t.topic_id 
FROM topic t
WHERE t.topic_publish = 1 
      t.topic_type <> 'topic' 
      t.topic_lang = 'en'  
ORDER BY t.topic_date_add DESC 
LIMIT 50;
```

The same index works for this.

Comment: Thanks, composite index helps, now average about 1s per query with `order`.  Can I do anything more?

Answer (score 0):

I would vote for (after removing the clutter of "topic_"):

Step 1:

```
INDEX(publish, lang,   -- the '=' columns
      date_add,        -- hoping that the optimizer will move to ORDER BY
      type, blog_id, id)  -- for "covering"
```

If it consumes the `ORDER BY`, then the sorting pass won't be needed.  However, it will have to skip over an indeterminate number of rows due to `type <> 'topic'`.

Step 2:  That may as well be `UNIQUE` instead of `INDEX`.  And, unless it will slow down other queries, toss your `UNIQUE`.

Step 3:  Then, rearrange the keys to avoid bouncing between the secondary keys and the `PRIMARY KEY` & data:

```
PRIMARY KEY(.. those 6 columns ..),  -- for "clustering"
INDEX(id),   -- To keep AUTO_INCREMENT happy.
...   -- any other keys you still need.
```